# Why doesn't Jenkins stop processing after a failed build step?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I'm running into an issue where Jenkins is continuing on to subsequent build steps even when the prior build step has failed. This is for setting up a Jenkins free-style job.

The build steps I'm running into an issue with are for "Trigger/call builds on other projects" steps, I am selecting/checking the option for "Block until the triggered projects finish their builds" and setting the parent job to mark the build result the same as the triggered jobs.

So say I have Job_1, Job_2, and Job_3 scheduled in sequence using the above options. Job_1 passes just fine, then Job_2 fails. In the Jenkins logs it shows Job_2 failing and marking the parent job as failed. However, the parent job still continues on to Job_3 even after marking itself as failed.

Here's an example from the Jenkins console output; notice how Job_2 failed and build result was changed to failure, but 1 second later Jenkins still kicks of Job_3 even though the build is already marked as failure:

```
12:34:54  Waiting for the completion of Job_1
12:48:44  Job_1 #7 completed. result was SUCCESS
12:48:44  Build step 'Trigger/call builds on other projects' changed build result to SUCCESS
12:48:45  Waiting for the completion of Job_2
18:18:44  Job_2 #169 completed. result was FAILURE
18:18:44  Build step 'Trigger/call builds on other projects' changed build result to FAILURE
18:18:45  Waiting for the completion of Job_3
18:38:25  Job_3 #180 completed. result was SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue is with the trigger parameterized builds plug-in. For some reason they thought it would be a good idea to continue on to subsequent build steps even if a build step that is a blocking call fails and calls the invoking parent job to fail.

Looks like I gotta do things myself or switch to Bamboo...